# Auto-Increment Number Field in a SharePoint List - But Not The Popular Solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I need to create an auto-increment field with a standard amount of digits. The format needs to be like this T000001, T000002, T000003, ......T000010, etc (7 Digits).  When it gets to the 10th record it should not do this **T000001**0 (8 digits).

I tried using the popular, often referenced solution (link below).  This method does not work as I hoped.  If you put it in a format like this T1000, when it gets to the 10th item it does this **T10001**0 rather than **T10010**.

**Here is the popular solution I already tried:**
https://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/how-to-create-an-auto-incrementing-number-field-in-a-sharepoint-list/

Comment: This isn't going to be very helpful as I can't remember the exact details, but like 7 years ago I had the exact same requirement as you. How I solved it was to use a SQL table to hold the "current" number of the IDs. Basically there was a row where the ID was the type of ID and there was a column with the current number (e.g. 7). Then whenever a new item was created, it looked at the database, retrieved the number and incremented by one, then wrote that back to the datatase. I believe it was through InfoPath but you might be able to do the same sort of thing with SharePoint Workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery to get list item count and init for Auto-Increment Field, this can avoid item delete.

Insert script editor webpart into list new form and insert the script into script editor webpart(Update the TxtField to your field name).

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    var site = "site Name";
    function pad(n, width, z) {
        z = z || '0';
        n = n + '';
        return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/ItemCount",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {                    
                if (data.d.ItemCount > 0) {
                    var field = "T1000"+pad(data.d.ItemCount, 3);
                    $("input[title='TxTField']").val(field).prop("disabled", true);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error: " + data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

[image]